# How to fix problem with angular schematics navigation hiding sidebar?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use the angular schematics navigation for a simple setup.
Everything works fine, besides that when I am refreshing the page, the sidebar/ burger menu is hided. Only if I resize the browser window, the sidebar/ burger menu appears.

What is the problem?

navigation.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>shape-cms</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

navigation.component.ts

```
export class NavigationComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      share()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

Comment: Maybe weird to ask but why you not make an `ngIf="isHandset$"` on the mat-sidenav-container. What this will do is wait for the `$isHandset` to be defined and then show it in the dom, this way it will not be loaded when isHandset is undefined.

Comment: I tried `ngIf="isHandset$"` but there is still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `share()` everything worked fine!

```
export class NavigationComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```